# JW Player not working in Chrome

Tags: php, embed, jwplayer

Iam using JW Player in the website to play youtube videos. I have used embed code for that. It is working properly in all browsers when executing the file from my local diretory. But it is not working in google chrome when executing the file from the server. Below is the code.

```
<embed id="ply" height="384" width="430" flashvars="autostart=true&repeat=always&file=http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNBFihPwThM&screencolor=000000&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=ffffff&skin=http://www.creatingafamily.org/modules/mod_jwmedia/skins/snel.swf" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="ply" style="" src="http://www.creatingafamily.org/modules/mod_jwmedia/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Please help to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all , we should let jwplayer's javascript to build the html code.

Initilaize jwplayer with js, and use HTML5 video in html like this:

```
<center>            
    <video controls="controls" id="container" poster="http://www.example.com/yourvideothumbs/videothumb.jpg"  width="693" height="388">
            <source src="http://www.example.com/videos/jourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>                        
</center>
```

Javascript:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(android)/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(chrom)/) ){
    //wee must force flash video player in chrome, because mp4 video files is not supported yet in chrome's HTML5 video implementation.
    modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}];
}else{
    modes = [ {type: 'html5'},{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]swf/player.swf'}];
}

jwplayer("container").setup({                   
    'modes':modes,      
});
```

This worked me in all browsers. jwplayer can conform if is HTML5 supported or not.

Or the below with forced HTML4 implementation:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
       modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}], //force flashplayer for video
       image: "yourvideothumbs/videothumb.jpg", //poster image
       file: "videos/jourvideo.mp4",  //video file 
       height: "693", //set height in px
       width: "388" //set width in px
   });
```

And in setup you can set `skin`, `controls`, `autostart` anything you want:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player/

Comment: Iam using HTML4. I need to do in HTML4

Comment: The js converts it to embed object if use only this:
`modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}]`
for mode.
I wrote a HTML4 implementation too, and it is forced to use flash player.

Comment: I added a HTML4 example to answer.

Comment: I used it only for files on server. For youtube videos i use the embed code of youtube. As i know youtube does not provide the direct access of the videos, so i does not believe it could work well, but there always could be a working hack :)

Comment: That code posted above is perfect, and it will work fine with YouTube videos as well.

Comment: I'm a lil bit confused. I'm facing the same problem over here. Where did you get this     modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}];     is it a default for Chrome and Android? Help a newbie.

Comment: Hi! when i used this code the re was problems with mp4 html5 video playing in chrome browsers and on android platforms default browser.
So i forced this.  Here is a simplier way to force flash: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29239/flash-as-primary
this modes defined by jwplayer. there is two modes, html5 and flash.

Comment: By default, both allowed and jwplayer decides whitch to use. Jw player's decision is always good except in chrome and android ( this examine only, is html5 video supported or not, but can not examine whitch video formats can be played by the browser, so i did this little change, see upper. Where i force flash on this cases )

Comment: And of corse, you should download the jwplayer from the jwplayer's website, and subtitute [JWPLAYERBASEDIR] with the path where you inserted jwplayers code in your webdirectory.

Comment: That means, I should still put your javascript code for forcing flash? even after inserting the code from the jwplayer website? Hope you get my point? Thanks!